# jQuery - redirect after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, however im having a problem getting window.location to work

```
$('.test_container a').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
            url: $(link).attr('href'),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#lightbox').show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#lightbox').hide();

                window.location(data);
            }
        });


    return false;
});
```

If window.location.replace is used instead it does work, however this then doesnt allow the brwser back buttons to work.

Does anyone know of any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of:

```
window.location(data);
```

Use:

```
window.location = data;
```

The `location` is a *property* of the `window` object not a *method*.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, i tried

```
window.location = data;
```

without success, but when  used

```
document.location.href = data;
```

it worked, you can consider this too